# What is the effect of correlated data on hypothesis testing with a linear mixed model?

Tags: hypothesis-testing, statistical-significance, mathematical-statistics, anova, intraclass-correlation

In 1987, Scariano & Davenport cautioned that non-independence of data had marked effects on hypothesis testing with an ANOVA model (Stephen M. Scariano and James M. Davenport The Effects of Violations of Independence Assumptions in the One-Way ANOVA; The American Statistician, Vol. 41, No. 2 [May, 1987], pp. 123-129.)

A similar conclusion was reached by John Walsh in 1947 (Walsh, J.E. [1947] Concerning the Effects of Intraclass Correlation on Certain Significance
Tests. Annals of Mathematical Statistics, 18, 88-96).

Walsh shows that the basic issue is that the distribution of the sample variance is not from the usual $\chi^2$ distribution (the multiplier is modified). This has spill on effects for the *t*-and *F*- distributions. Scariano reaches the same conclusions.

These cautions seem to go beyond the problem of obtaining an estimate of the variance from correlated data.

The Walsh/Scariano correction factor for the t-test is given by $$ \sqrt{\frac{1 - \rho}{1 + (n - 1)\rho}}$$

Running some simulations on a model of a replicated experiment with a control and treatment group (a clustered, balanced randomised block design) indicates that we obtain similar *t*-tests if we treat this as a lmm and use the correction factor as we do to collapsing the replicates to means and performing a two-group *t*-test, regardless of the treatment effect or the $\rho$. Without the correction factor, provided the $\rho$ is positive, we obtain much larger *t*-statistics.

My question is: Why do we not apply the Walsh/Scariano correction factor in hypothesis testing with a linear mixed model? It may not be straightforward to calculate the $\rho$, but in some cases it could be.